# Can't get javascript to target more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code so far works for the first 2 divs but it doesn't hide the other ones i place, also i am stuck on how to make the javascript work for the remaining images. theres a total of 4 thumbnails that when you click, the large photo appears next to it

```
<div class="gallery">
<div class="thumbs float-left">
    <div class="subnav float-left">
    <ul>
    <li class="gallery-btn"><a href="#" title="GALLERY"><img src="_images/shirts/shirt-1-thumb.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="video-btn"><a href="#" title="VIDEOS"><img src="_images/shirts/shirt-2-thumb.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="video-btn"><a href="#" title="VIDEOS"><img src="_images/shirts/shirt-3-thumb.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="video-btn"><a href="#" title="VIDEOS"><img src="_images/shirts/shirt-4-thumb.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- END OF SUBNAV -->

</div>

<div class="largethumb float-left">

    <div class="gallery-area float-right">
    <img src="_images/shirts/shirt1.jpg">
    </div><!-- END OF AREA 01 -->

    <div class="video-area float-right">
    <img src="_images/shirts/shirt2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//  HIDE & SHOW ---------------------------------------------------

$(".video-area").hide();    // START BY HIDING THE VIDEOS DIV  
                        // NOTE: USE ID NAMES NOT CLASS NAMES  

    $(".gallery-btn").click(function () {   //CLICK ON THE LINK TO SHOW 1 DIV AND HIDE ANOTHER
    $(".gallery-area").fadeIn(500);         //SHOW GALLERY   // FADE IN OVER 3 SECONDS
    $(".video-area").hide();                    //HIDE VIDEOS  // FADE OUT OVER 3 SECONDS
    return false;
 }); //closes function

 $(".video-btn").click(function () {        //CLICK ON THE LINK TO SHOW 1 DIV AND HIDE ANOTHER
    $(".video-area").fadeIn(500);           //SHOW VIDEOS  // FADE IN OVER 3 SECONDS
    $(".gallery-area").hide();                  //HIDE GALLERY  // FADE OUT OVER 3 SECONDS
    return false;
 }); //closes function

  $(".video-btn2").click(function () {   //CLICK ON THE LINK TO SHOW 1 DIV AND HIDE ANOTHER
  $(".video-area2").fadeIn(500);     //SHOW VIDEOS  // FADE IN OVER 3 SECONDS
    $(".gallery-area").hide();          //HIDE GALLERY  // FADE OUT OVER 3 SECONDS
    return false;
 }); //closes function
```

Comment: What? What divs are you trying to hide that don't hide? Also, the code that *initially* hides the video area--is that in a jQuery ready function?

Comment: Your html has no element with "video-btn2" or "video-area2" classes.  You probably want to be using ids for this.

Comment: You're probably wanting $("video-btn")[1] instead. Jquery returns an array of all matches elements so you can treat it like an array. Also when assigning click methods and some other jquery functions it will automatically do it to all matched elements

Comment: Note also that this code should probably be cleaned up a lot, and you probably don't really *need* anything other than a single click handler for all the links with some minor `data` values and/or simple jQuery selectors.